# Alternative solution to SNAT for particular use case

Tags: linux, routing, nat

I have the following setup. If I add a SNAT rule in VM I can successfully route PC traffic through VM (instead of sending it to Ethernet directly) means I can connect to internet.
[image]

The rule is:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens37 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.3
```

**Details:**
Windows 10 in PC and debian 10 in VM. I get internet access through TPLink modem. Everything is in /24. Gateway is set on VMNet1 and is 192.168.2.3.

**Question:**
Why I can't connect to 192.168.1.1 without adding a SNAT? Is there any alternative solution(no SNAT and MASQUERADE)?
I don't have any problem with SNAT just ask this question to know the reason.